# java Integer reference

Tags: java

I've got a question.

```
public class Jaba {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer i = new Integer(0);        
        new A(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        new B(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        int ii = 0;        
        new A(ii);
        System.out.println(ii);
        new B(ii);
        System.out.println(ii);    
    }

}

class A {

    public A(Integer i) { ++i; }

}

class B {

    public B(int i) { ++i; }

}
```

To my mind passing an int\Integer as Integer to a function and making ++ on that reference should change the underlying object, but the output is 0 in all the cases. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the other answers, Java does only *call-by-value*, and the `++` operator only effects a variable, not an object. If you want to simulate *call-by-reference*, you would need to pass a mutable object, like an array, and modify its elements.

The Java API has some specialized objects for this, like `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` (which additionally also works over multiple threads), and `org.omg.CORBA.IntHolder` (used for call-by-reference for remote calls by the CORBA mechanism).

But you can also simply define your own mutable integer:

```
class MutableInteger {
    public int value;
}


class C {
   public C(int[] i) {
       ++i[0];
   }
}
class D {
   public D(MutableInteger i) {
       ++i.value;
   }
}
class E {
   public E(AtomicInteger i) {
       i.incrementAndGet();
   }
}
public class Jaba {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] iii = new int[]{ 0 };
        System.out.println(iii[0]);
        new C(iii);
        System.out.println(iii[0]);
        MutableInteger mi = new MutableInteger();
        System.out.println(mi.value);
        new D(mi);
        System.out.println(mi.value);
        MutableInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
        System.out.println(ai);
        new E(ai);
        System.out.println(ai);
    }
}
```

Comment: java only does call by sharing

Answer (score 12):

Most of the classes such as `Integer` that derive from Java's abstract `Number` class are *immutable*., i.e. once constructed, they can only ever contain that particular number.

A useful benefit of this is that it permits *caching*.  If you call:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(n);
```

for `-128 <= n < 127` instead of:

```
Integer i = Integer.new(n)
```

you get back a cached object, rather than a new object.  This saves memory and increases performance.

In the latter test case with a bare `int` argument, all you're seeing is how Java's variables are passed *by value* rather than *by reference*.

Comment: Actually, the `Number` class simply is abstract and stateless - and there are subclasses that *are mutable* (AtomicInteger and AtomicLong are such ones, and one also could define new custom ones).

Answer (score 5):

@Alnitak -> correct. And to add what really happens here. The ++i due to autoboxing works like that:

```
int val = Integer.intValue(); ++val;
```

and val is not stored anywhere, thus increment is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use reference parameter then try this.

IntHolder
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/IntHolder.html